# How to use this trigger on table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am not able to get the value of variable `v` when I fire this trigger on my table:

```
create or replace trigger tri
after insert or update or delete on site_sector

declare
    v number;
begin
    if inserting then
        v:=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line('There is :'||v||' row affected');
    elsif updating then
        v:=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line('There is :'||v||' row affected');
    elsif deleting then
        v:=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line('There is :'||v||' row affected');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('There is no row affected');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: sql%rowcount is cleared (set null) at the start of a statement, and set to number of rows after statement processing completes. However, statement processing is not complete until all triggers have been processed. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4ac24446e9077e6c7d857fa86df5ee6).

Answer (score 0):

Well, that won't work; something like this might.

Sample table:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 ID                                                             NUMBER
```

Compound trigger: declare a variable which will be incremented in `BEFORE EACH ROW`; number of rows affected is then displayed in `AFTER STATEMENT`.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger tri
  2    for insert or update or delete on test
  3    compound trigger
  4
  5    g_cnt number := 0;
  6
  7    before each row is
  8    begin
  9      g_cnt := g_cnt + 1;
 10    end before each row;
 11
 12    after statement is
 13    begin
 14      dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows affected = ' || g_cnt);
 15    end after statement;
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (id)
  2  select level from dual connect by level <= 5;
Number of rows affected = 5

5 rows created.

SQL> update test set id = id + 10 where id <= 3;
Number of rows affected = 3

3 rows updated.

SQL> delete from test where id < 10;
Number of rows affected = 2

2 rows deleted.

SQL>
```

Messages "match"; that's why I wonder where you'll be using this, as Oracle shows that info anyway.